# Batch File - Add calculated date to end of file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Hello and thanks for any help in advance! I'm in need of some expert help related to a batch script I'm using to add a date to the end of a `.xlsx` file.

The current script I have works fine and adds the current date to the end of the file, but what I need is to add the current date minus 12 days, along with the current date minus 6 days, to the end of the file in the following format:

```
Test 20160807-20160813.xlsx.
```

So its the file name `Test`, then `YYYYMMDD (minus 12) - YYYYMMDD (minus 6).xlsx`

Here is the script I'm currently using that gets the current date:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%F in ("C:\test*.xlsx") do ( set "MDate=%%~tF" 
set "ParsedDate=!MDate:~6,4!!MDate:~0,2!!MDate:~3,2!" copy %%F%%~dpnF!ParsedDate!%%~xF.new )

for %%F in ("C:\test*.xlsx") do ( del %%F )

ren "C:\test*.new" *.

exit
```

The output is `Test20160815.xlsx`, but I need `Test 20160807-20160813.xlsx`. Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is all much, much easier if you use PowerShell rather than trying to do date arithmetic in batch (shell script).

Comment: Thanks for the input Bill, can you provide a solution in PowerShell?

Comment: You could embed other scripts into [tag:batch-file] that support true date/time arithmetics, like VBScript or JavaScript; of course, PowerShell could also be implemented...

Comment: @RyanPierce - gave an example in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example in PowerShell:

```
$today = [DateTime]::Today
$date1 = $today.AddDays(-12)
$date2 = $today.AddDays(-6)
"Test {0:yyyyMMdd}-{1:yyyyMMdd}.xlsx" -f ($date1),($date2)
```

In PowerShell, dates are not strings. They are first-class objects. In this example, `$today` gets assigned today's date (a `[DateTime]` object, not a string). `$date1` gets 12 days before today's date, and `$date2` gets 6 days before today's date. The last line of code uses PowerShell's format (`-f`) operator to output a customized string containing the dates in the format you want.