# Batch File - Add calculated date to end of file

Tags: batch-file

Hello and thanks for any help in advance!  I'm in need of some expert help related to a batch script I'm using to add a date to the end of a .xlsx file.  The current script I have works fine and adds the current date to the end of the file, but what I need is to add the current date minus 12 days along with the current date minus 6 days to the end of the file in the following format: Test 20160807-20160813.xlsx.  So its the file name Test then YYYYMMDD (minus 12) - YYYYMMDD (minus 6).xlsx

Here is the script I'm current using that gets the current date:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%F in ("C:\test\*.xlsx") do ( 
    set "MDate=%%~tF"
    set "ParsedDate=!MDate:~6,4!!MDate:~0,2!!MDate:~3,2!"
    copy %%F %%~dpnF!ParsedDate!%%~xF.new )

for %%F in ("C:\test\*.xlsx") do ( 
    del %%F )

ren "C:\test\*.new" *.

exit
```

Output is `Test20160815.xlsx` and I need Test `20160807-20160813.xlsx`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch File - Add calculated date to end of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960162/batch-file-add-calculated-date-to-end-of-file)

Comment: PowerShell will make your life so much easier (like I mentioned in your duplicate question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Batch Script - Subtracting (or adding) Days from Current Day Simplified

You can do this using a batch script that sets the date variable and subtracts 1 day (or any number of days for that matter) from the current date which the batch script is executed.

I put more comments in the script to explain what each variable does and so on too, but basically you set the variables in the batch script as usual, and it'll use those to build three dynamic VB Scripts per date calculations needed (the for minus 6 and three minus 12) to do the date subtraction calculation, add leading zeros where needed, and so forth for the YYYY, MM, and DD variables.

**To add:** You can also use this script to add a number of days to the current date by deleting the minus **(`-`)**
 symbol from the below batch script in the **`:DynamicVBSScriptBuild`** routine, so where you see this`,-%MinusDay%,` you simple remove the minus symbol to get `,%MinusDay%,` on each of those lines and now the `MinusDay=` variable value will equal the number of days you want to add.

**Important Note:** It seems that five 9's (`99999`) is the limit on the batch script when subtracting with the `MinusDays=` value. It also seems that six 9's (`999999`) is the limit on the batch script when adding with the `MinusDays=` value.

*(I plugged in your batch logic where it needs to be minus a few adjustments to handle files with spaces, and so on but these are set as `SET MinusDay12=12`
and S`ET MinusDay6=6` for the -12 and the -6 days value for the calculation.)*

**Batch Script**

```
 @ECHO ON

::// Minus days is the number of days to subtract from the CURRENT DAY i.e. 2 for minus 2 days or 99999 for minus 99999 days from when it's run
SET MinusDay12=12
SET MinusDay6=6

:: This calls the temp vbs script routine that will be used to set YYYY-MM-DD values for the subtracted days date you specify
CALL :DynamicVBSScriptBuild

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('cscript//nologo "%YYYYTmpVBS12%"') DO SET YYYY12=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('cscript//nologo "%MMTmpVBS12%"') DO SET MM12=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('cscript//nologo "%DDTmpVBS12%"') DO SET DD12=%%A

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('cscript//nologo "%YYYYTmpVBS6%"') DO SET YYYY6=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('cscript//nologo "%MMTmpVBS6%"') DO SET MM6=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('cscript//nologo "%DDTmpVBS6%"') DO SET DD6=%%A

::// Set variables for YYYY MM DD values accordingly
SET DateValue12=%YYYY12%%MM12%%DD12%
SET DateValue6=%YYYY6%%MM6%%DD6%

SET SourceDir=C:\Test
FOR %%F in ("%SourceDir%\*.xlsx") DO ( 
    COPY /Y "%%~F" "%%~DPNF%DateValue12%-%DateValue6%%%~xF.new" )

FOR %%F IN ("%SourceDir%\*.xlsx") DO ( 
    DEL /Q /F "%%~F" )

REN "%SourceDir%\*.new" *.

EXIT /B

GOTO EOF

:DynamicVBSScriptBuild
SET YYYYTmpVBS12=%temp%\~tmp_yyyy12.vbs
SET MMTmpVBS12=%temp%\~tmp_mm12.vbs
SET DDTmpVBS12=%temp%\~tmp_dd12.vbs
SET YYYYTmpVBS6=%temp%\~tmp_yyyy6.vbs
SET MMTmpVBS6=%temp%\~tmp_mm6.vbs
SET DDTmpVBS6=%temp%\~tmp_dd6.vbs
IF EXIST "%YYYYTmpVBS12%" DEL /Q /F "%YYYYTmpVBS12%"
IF EXIST "%MMTmpVBS12%" DEL /Q /F "%MMTmpVBS12%"
IF EXIST "%DDTmpVBS12%" DEL /Q /F "%DDTmpVBS12%"
IF EXIST "%YYYYTmpVBS6%" DEL /Q /F "%YYYYTmpVBS6%"
IF EXIST "%MMTmpVBS6%" DEL /Q /F "%MMTmpVBS6%"
IF EXIST "%DDTmpVBS6%" DEL /Q /F "%DDTmpVBS6%"
ECHO dt = DateAdd("d",-%MinusDay12%,date) >> "%YYYYTmpVBS12%"
ECHO yyyy = Year(dt)                    >> "%YYYYTmpVBS12%"
ECHO WScript.Echo yyyy                  >> "%YYYYTmpVBS12%"
ECHO dt = DateAdd("d",-%MinusDay12%,date) >> "%MMTmpVBS12%"
ECHO mm = Right("0" ^& Month(dt),2)     >> "%MMTmpVBS12%"
ECHO WScript.Echo mm                    >> "%MMTmpVBS12%"
ECHO dt = DateAdd("d",-%MinusDay12%,date) >> "%DDTmpVBS12%"
ECHO dd = Right("0" ^& Day(dt),2)       >> "%DDTmpVBS12%"
ECHO WScript.Echo dd                    >> "%DDTmpVBS12%"
ECHO dt = DateAdd("d",-%MinusDay6%,date) >> "%YYYYTmpVBS6%"
ECHO yyyy = Year(dt)                    >> "%YYYYTmpVBS6%"
ECHO WScript.Echo yyyy                  >> "%YYYYTmpVBS6%"
ECHO dt = DateAdd("d",-%MinusDay6%,date) >> "%MMTmpVBS6%"
ECHO mm = Right("0" ^& Month(dt),2)     >> "%MMTmpVBS6%"
ECHO WScript.Echo mm                    >> "%MMTmpVBS6%"
ECHO dt = DateAdd("d",-%MinusDay6%,date) >> "%DDTmpVBS6%"
ECHO dd = Right("0" ^& Day(dt),2)       >> "%DDTmpVBS6%"
ECHO WScript.Echo dd                    >> "%DDTmpVBS6%"
GOTO EOF
```

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [**CSCRIPT**](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)
- [**DateAdd**](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_dateadd.asp)

Comment: This worked Flawlessly!  I greatly appreciate your help along with the time you took to thoroughly explain the code and incorporating my original logic into the solution.  If there where any way to give you additional points I would, along with buying you a few rounds of drinks!

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested to see how PJI's works out on September 1st.  I can't seem to find where the checks are in the above code for when the day of the month is actually less than the 13th.  I couldn't get past this without creating an index of dates and then subtracting 12 from the index number.  I worked on this yesterday and actually bumped the subtraction up to 16 days so that I was able to confirm that 16 days ago, yesterday, returned a result of July 30th.

I created one, but didn't get it out in time before the previous responder, but I was trying to minimize the complexity.  However, mine relies on an outside source of information... an index file (CSV format) with dates in it.  i made it 1,000 days long as of the first of this year.

You must put the CSV file in the same location that the batch file's being "run in."  I put that in quotes because you can change the run location in task scheduler.  But most of the time, you just put the CSV file in the same folder as the batch file: [dateidx.csv](http://www.pcfixerguy.com/dateidx.csv)

#### Expanded View of Code

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=,D" %i in ('type dateidx.csv ^| find /i "%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%"') do (set dateidxnum=%j)
set /a days12ago=%dateidxnum%-12
set /a days6ago=%dateidxnum%-6
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %m in ('type dateidx.csv ^| find "D%days12ago%"') DO (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %q in ('type dateidx.csv ^| find "D%days6ago%"') DO (
    echo %m-%q.xlsx
    )
)
```

May change the echo line above to rename the file how you'd like. You would use the following:

```
rename oldfilename.xlsx %m-%q.xlsx
```

I put the echo in the example so you can see the funtion work.

#### Collapsed View of Code as you would have it in a batch file

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=,D" %i in ('type dateidx.csv ^| find /i "%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%"') do (set dateidxnum=%j)
set /a days12ago=%dateidxnum%-12
set /a days6ago=%dateidxnum%-6
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %m in ('type dateidx.csv ^| find "D%days12ago%"') DO (for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %q in ('type dateidx.csv ^| find "D%days6ago%"') DO (echo %m-%q.xlsx))
```

4 lines.

Here's a screen shot of the batch code above in the code block copied and pasted into command prompt.  I put the dateidx.csv file in the c:\test folder:
[image]